# Unable to recover my login shell

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, iterm

I'm experiencing a problem with my shell (Iterm+zsh).
I had zsh 4.3.1 installed and I was trying to install the 5.0.2 version then, in the middle of the installation process (I was doing it with Homebrew) I closed the Iterm window and then, at the next opening, the window started closing automatically after one/two seconds.

I've tried to log-out and then log-in again but nothing happened.
I've tried to restart my machine and then...nothing!
Iterm keeps starting and then switching off and, after some times, a pop up comes out saying :
" Short-Lived Session Warning " and the Iterm window was displaying login: /usr/local/bin/zsh: No such file or directory.

An other point in favor to my dumbness: I uninstalled the official Terminal app (which occasionally, gives me the ability to, at least, switch to different shell) just before starting to upgrade to zsh 5.0.2.

Now I tried to remove all the zsh files (I know, second dumb move) and I don't know how to switch my login shell back to bash to reinstall properly the updated version of zsh.

Here you can find a link with the code of some of my shell configuration files:

- etc/zshenv
- etc/zprofile
- etc/shells
- etc/paths
- Users/myusername/.login

https://gist.github.com/omargourari/7587930

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new iTerm profile which runs something like `/bin/bash` or `/bin/zsh` instead of your login shell, then open a window with that profile.

Comment: This was the move.Thank you so much. I was able to switch to bash and reinstall the latest version.

Comment: Fixed for me too, thanks!